# Reorder pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following groupby dataframe in pandas

```
Crop            Region   
maize_1         Temperate    30.0
                Tropical     46.0
maize_2         Tropical     77.5
                Temperate    13.5
soybean_1       Temperate    18.5
                Tropical     35.0
```

How can I sort it so that in the 'Region' Column, Temperate preceedes Tropical?

-- EDIT: expected answer is

```
Crop            Region   
maize_1         Temperate    30.0
                Tropical     46.0
maize_2         Temperate    13.5
                Tropical     77.5
soybean_1       Temperate    18.5
                Tropical     35.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('maize_1', 'Temperate'), ('maize_1', 'Tropical'),
                                 ('maize_2', 'Tropical'), ('maize_2', 'Temperate'),
                                 ('soybean_1', 'Temperate'), ('soybean_1', 'Tropical')],
                               names=['Crop', 'Region'])
s = pd.Series([30., 46., 77.5, 13.5, 18.5, 34.], idx)

s

Crop       Region   
maize_1    Temperate    30.0
           Tropical     46.0
maize_2    Tropical     77.5
           Temperate    13.5
soybean_1  Temperate    18.5
           Tropical     34.0
dtype: float64
```

#### Solution

IIUC you want to sort by `'Region'` and leave `'Crop'` alone.

```
s.unstack().sort_index(1).stack()

Crop       Region   
maize_1    Temperate    30.0
           Tropical     46.0
maize_2    Temperate    13.5
           Tropical     77.5
soybean_1  Temperate    18.5
           Tropical     34.0
dtype: float64
```

You can also, sort the index as is but it will also sort `'Crop'`.  It so happens your `'Crop'`s are already in order.  But if they weren't, this solution would preserve that.

Comment: thanks @piRSquared, however your solution is slightly different from what I want. I will clarify my question.

Comment: `level` kwarg needs to be `[0, 1]`

Comment: Good call with not sorting `Crop`!

Answer (score 0):

Check out `sortlevel` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html)) or `sort_index` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)).

```
df.sortlevel(level=[0, 1])
```

and

```
df.sort_index(level=[0, 1])
```

both output

```
Crop       Region   
maize_1    Temperate      30
           Tropical     46.0
maize_2    Temperate    13.5
           Tropical     77.5
soybean_1  Temperate    18.5
           Tropical     35.0
```